# C arrays and functions, how to return?

Tags: c, arrays, return-type

I have a newbie question regarding array and functions in C.

Let's say I have this array:

```
int array1[10] = {2,4,6,3,2,3,6,7,9,1};
```

I wrote this function:

```
int *reverseArray(int *array, int size)
{
    int *arr = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    int i, j;

    for(i = 10, j = 0; i > 0; i--, i++) {
        arr[j] = array[i];
    }

    return arr;
}
```

I don't even know if it works, because if I do:

```
array1 = reverseArray(array1, 10);
```

I got the error:

*assignment to expression with array type*

How do I assign the adress of an array to another array?

Comment: yes i is j, was a typo, thank you man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is correct<sup>*</sup>, and it works fine. The problem is that you cannot assign an array like this:

```
array1 = reverseArray(array1, 10);
```

`reverseArray` returns a pointer, so you should assign it to a pointer variable:

```
int* reversedArray1 = reverseArray(array1, 10);
```

If you want the data to be placed back in `array1`, use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(array1, reversedArray1, sizeof(array1));
free(reversedArray1);
```

Note that since your function uses `malloc` to allocate its return value, the caller needs to deallocate this memory after it is done with it. You need to call `free(reversedArray1)` to ensure that the allocated array does not create a memory leak.

<sup>*</sup> Use `size-1` in place of 10 in the `for` loop header, since you are passing it anyway, and allow `i` to reach zero:

```
for(i = size-1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++)
```

Comment: I thought an array was nothing but a pointer to the first element. Ok now it works.
Since ponters and arrays are so different, is there a way to return an array from a function?

Comment: @Carondimonio An array becomes a pointer to the initial element when you pass it to a function or assign it to a pointer variable. In other situations an array is an array, not a pointer. Implicit conversion to pointer make this distinction rather obscure, though.

Comment: @Carondimonio you can't return an array directly from a function. You could return a struct containing an array though.